# Calculating p-value from chi-square when comparing two incidence rates

Tags: chi-squared-test, p-value, incidence-rate-ratio

I am trying to follow [this guide](http://www.statsdirect.com/help/default.htm#rates/incidence_rates.htm) to calculate the p-value from an incidence rate between two samples.

The raw data is patients' use of an action plan before and after education.

Before education 7 uses over 44.17 patient years were observed.
After education 41 uses over 101.5 patient years were observed.
Totals are then 48 uses over 145.67 patient years.

So I think following the guide the chi^2 value is:
(41 - (48*101.5)/145.67 )^2  ((48*44.17*101.5) / 145.67^2)  = [5.627](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2841%20-%20%2848*101.5%29%2F145.67%20%29%5E2%20%2F%20%28%2848*44.17*101.5%29%20%2F%C2%A0145.67%5E2%29).

How can I go from this chi^2 value to a p-value? Most calculators I can find online require a Degrees of Freedom parameter, but I'm not sure what that means in this context?